# create.js.erb is called only one time after form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a simple_form_for in my project. My goal is to alert people when their email is already in database thanks to an alert and ajax to reload the form if there is an error. When I send my form for the first time, I get the good respond from create.js.erb. But if I send the form a second time without reloading the page with the browser, my controller create method code is taken into account but not my create.js.erb code. For example, if I put an alert in the create.js.erb file, it doesn't pop the second time I send the form by clicking on the button again. Can you help me to figure why ?

**pages_controller.rb**

```
 def create
    @email = waiting_list_params[:email]
    @waiting_user = WaitingList.new(waiting_list_params)
    respond_to do |format|
    if @waiting_user.save
        UserMailer.welcome(@email).deliver_now
        format.html { redirect_to concours_path }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render 'pages/concours' }
        format.js { flash[:error] = @waiting_user.errors.full_messages[0] }
      end
    end
  end
```

**create.js.erb**

```
   function refreshForm(innerHTML) {
  const newForm = document.getElementById("concours-form");
  newForm.innerHTML = innerHTML;
}


<% if @waiting_user.errors.any? %>
  refreshForm('<%= j render "pages/concours_form" %>');
  confPopup.style.display = "none";
<% else %>
  confPopup.style.display = "flex";
<% end %>
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for @waiting_user, {id: 'concours-form', url: concours_path, remote: true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.text_field :email,
      class: "landing-form-input",
      autocomplete: "off",
      required: true,
      pattern: '[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}',
      placeholder: "Renseignez ton email ici"
    %>
  <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
  <%= f.hidden_field :concours_city,
      value:'',
      id: 'c-choosen-city'
    %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :source,
      value: params[:source]
    %>
  <%= f.button :submit,
      class: "landing-form-button",
      value: "Je tente ma chance !"
    %>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
get 'concours', to: 'pages#concours'
post 'concours', to: 'pages#create'
```

Comment: Can you post the server log for both the scenarios?

Comment: Sure. First submit with an error in form : `WaitingList Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "waiting_lists" WHERE "waiting_lists"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "test@test.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendering pages/create_concours.js.erb
  Rendered pages/_concours_form.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered pages/create_concours.js.erb (5.8ms)`

Comment: Second submit after correcting the error : `Rendering pages/create_concours.js.erb
  Rendered pages/create_concours.js.erb (57.9ms)`

Comment: Well, if there are no errors, then only `confPopup.style.display = "flex";` will be executed according to your code. Is it getting executed?

Comment: Only on the first submit. On the second submit nothing is executed. Not even an alert in the create.js.erb

Comment: you use turbolinks? see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18770589/2144445

Comment: No, I don't use turbolinks !

Comment: I isolated the bug on this repo : github.com/Bonapara/simple_form_bug if you want to have a better idea of my problem !

Comment: Solved. I had to use `var confPopup = document.querySelector('.waiting-list-conf-popup') || '';` in order to not redeclare variables each time